# What the best simulator to connect with ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have once underwater robot with six thruster (Dc motors), and I want to create swarm of underwater robots. It is more difficult to create the swarm in practice.

For this reason i want to simulate the swarm of underwater robots to work with ROS.

I don't know what is the best and suitable for the underwater robots and water environment such as the drag, density and pressure that connect with ROS.
Any suggestion ...??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69436/what-the-best-simulator-to-connect-with-ros?/) by [underwater](https://answers.ros.org/users/1303/underwater/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-07-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-08-01**:
What aspects are you attempting to simulate? For example, are you trying to measure pressure differences at different parts of the environment? Are you trying to make sure that the drag causes motion dynamics in keeping with the real hardware so that you can tune motion controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't have any experience with underwater simulation, but maybe [UWSim](http://ros.org/wiki/UWSim) is what you're looking for.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2